# Error help "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, syntax

I'm getting this error with my code "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,location,authorname) VALUES ('','','','','','','','')' at line 1". I'm new to this and i was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what's wrong? Code:

```
<?PHP
include_once('header.php');
include_once('create.php');

$isbn=$_POST['isbn'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$publisher=$_POST['publisher'];
$genre=$_POST['genre'];
$availability=$_POST['availability'];
$condition=$_POST['condition'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$authorname=$_POST['authorname'];

$queryuser=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book 
    WHERE Title='$title' ");

$checktitle=mysql_num_rows($queryuser);

if($checktitle != 0){
echo "Sorry ".$title." is already added."; 
}

else {

$insert_book=mysql_query("INSERT INTO book (isbn,title,publisher,genre,availability,condition,location,authorname) VALUES ('$isbn','$title','$publisher','$genre','$availability','$condition','$location','$authorname')");

if($insert_book)
{ echo "<b>Addition successful.</b><br><b>You Added: </b>".$title."<br><b>By:  
</b>".$authorname ; }
else{
echo "error in registration".mysql_error(); 
}
}
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I always find it useful to output the entire SQL string and try using it in MySql Workbench.

Comment: `condition` is a reserved word

Comment: Print your query in php if any value contains a single quote or double quote. use mysql_real_escape_string() function

Comment: possible duplicate of [ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520960/ou-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-m)

Answer (score 1):

"condition" is a keyword in SQL.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO book (`isbn`,`title`,`publisher`,`genre`,`availability`,`condition`,`location`,`authorname`) VALUES ('$isbn','$title','$publisher','$genre','$availability','$condition','$location','$authorname')
```

Answer (score 0):

**condition** is not allowed as column name. Try renaming that mysql column to something else.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by **ANY** of the variables you inserted having a single quote (**'**).. To solve this issue you need to sanitize your variables taken from user input against SQL Injection. You also need to validate the form first. Please read on [How to prevent SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Also please do know that all **mysql_*** functions are now deprecated. Please consider using either PDO or Mysqli